# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2 +1}{2n^2 \sqrt{n} +5}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I show this series diverges $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2 +1}{2n^2 \sqrt{n} +5}$. I tried doing a root test, and end up with the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n^2+1)^{1/n}}{(2n^2\sqrt{n}+5)^{1/n}}$$

which ends up as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ after my calculations, which indicates convergence.

Comment: Your root test should give a limit of $1$, which is inconclusive.  Try a limit comparison test with $\sum 1/\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+1}{n^2}=1$, there is some $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies $\frac{n^2+1}{n^2}\ge \frac{1}{2}$. But then
$$
\sum_{n\ge N}\frac{n^2+1}{2n^{3/2}+5}\ge\sum_{n\ge N}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}+\frac{5}{n^2}}\ge\sum_{n\ge N}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}+2\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{n\ge N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\infty
$$

Answer (score 0):

Similar but alternative approach to Reveillark:

> How can I show this series diverges $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2 +1}{2n^2 \sqrt{n} +5}$.

Since the goal is to show divergence:

Without Loss of Generality (WLOG) the numerator can be **decreased** to $(n^2)$.

Then, WLOG, the expression can be changed to
$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n} + (5/[n^2])}.$

Then, WLOG, the denominator can be **increased** to $3\sqrt{n}$, with the understanding that in all but a finite number of terms, this change will be causing an increase in the denominator.

Then, WLOG, the factor of $(3)$ can be removed from the denominator, since if a series given by $\sum a_n$ diverges, so does the series $(1/3) \times \sum a_n.$

Finally, the rule can be invoked that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^s$ is divergent whenever $0 < s < 1.$